PJSIP - how to detect that a subscriber has rejected a call
I am writing an application on Ubuntu 22.04.4 with PJSUA/PJSIP. I took the code from PJSUA and corrected it for myself. Everything works well, except for one thing. If I make a call to a subscriber, and he rejects it, then I accept the PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONFIRMED event in the on_call_state function, i.e. call confirmed. In the speaker, the robot says that the subscriber is currently on the phone and cannot answer the call. When the robot completes its message, the following message will appear in the terminal: sound_port.c: EC suspended because of inactivity. After this, I have one active call, but in fact the subscriber disconnected a long time ago.
How to correct the situation, i.e. How to catch the moment that the subscriber has canceled the call in order to end the current call? I suppose I can catch the message sound_port.c: EC suspended because of inactivity, but I think there is a more elegant solution

Not sure if I understood the scenario, but I think you should catch PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED event and then do something like this:
pjsua_call_info call_info;
pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &call_info);

if (call_info.last_status == PJSIP_SC_BUSY_HERE) {
    // This is the moment when call is finished because callee is busy.
}


This does not work in my case. I'm doing a call state check in the on_call_state function. Moreover, if the subscriber pressed the Accept call button or he pressed the Cancel call button, then the call_info.state state will always be equal to 5, i.e. PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONFIRMED, and the state call_info.last_status will be equal to 200, i.e. PJSIP_SC_OK.

Still, in on_call_state callback handle PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED state and then check call_info.last_status. At some point you have to reach disconnected state. If not, then I believe something is broken in your SIP communication.
